# Firebase ref.set() removes text from other form fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just started learning Firebase.

I've a form on page, and it has multiple textarea elements. Every textarea has it's own submit button. When I write text in any one of the textarea and presses the submit button, the value saves in the db.

But if I type some text in Textarea-1 and leave it as it is, and then type some text in Textarea-2 and press submit button, the Textarea-2 value saves in the db but the text in other Textarea (in this case Textarea-1) will get removed.
In the function that saves the data, I'm also setting the Current date with this code:

```
addMyValues(val1, val2, val3, val4) {
this.db.database.ref('profiles/' + new Date().toDateString() + '/' + val1).push({
  name  : val2.dispName,
  email : val2.email,
  phone : val3
});
this.db.database.ref('birthDay/' + val1 + '/newUpdate').set(new Date().toDateString());   
}
```

What will causing the issue?

Comment: The text is removed from DB or on your front input ?

Comment: Front from the other textarea which was not submitted, whereas the values are saving.

Answer (score 0):

.set() will override the data in the document if you do not specify it to `merge`

Should be something like this:

```
this.db.database.doc('birthDay/' + val1 + '/newUpdate').set(new Date().toDateString(), { merge: true });
```

You need to set `merge` in the `set` method

Comment: Giving error: Argument of type {merge:boolean} is not assignable....
am I missing something here.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document - I also updated my answer which may be more accurate.